# RevTex4-1 a footnote spreading to both columns

Tags: bibliographies, footnotes, revtex

I am having trouble controlling the positioning of my footnotes in the bibliography in RevTex4-1. When the footnote is very big it will spread across both columns, how can I control it so that the footnote is only locate in the column that is started in IE it spreads downwards in one column instead of spreading across to the other column.

I hope that this is enough information to convey the problem I am having.

Comment: Welcome! Please post a small, compilable document (Minimum Working Example with Bibliography) which we can copy-paste-compile to reproduce the issue. This will make it much easier to help you! What's IE?

Comment: Hi, so, a few things (I'm writing this here so that you'll be able to see it when the 'answer' below gets merged with this post). First: Welcome to the site! Second, you are correct to show the output by taking a screenshot and uploading the picture. Third, you can put code in your questions and answers by simple copying and pasting the code, highlighting it, and using the code sample button (the one that looks like { }) or, by pressing Ctrl-k. Fourth, this isn't a forum or bulletin board, but a Q & A site. Answers must be answers, if you want to clarify or alter your question, simply edit it

Comment: Finally, you seem to have two accounts (at least). It's best to use one account, as all the rep you gain  will stay with the one account and that will unlock privileges as you get more rep (indicating more experience) which will help you when using the site. You will also have a better record of old questions and answers and it's better for the community too - it stops people from voting on their own questions to game the system ("sock puppetry") and it means that, if you are ever disciplined in any way, you can't just log on with another account. It let's the community know who's who